# Code optimization: while or for (or anything else)?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this (I'm using integer progressive number for sake of simplicity, but they are actually float FX rates):

```
List = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]     #__len__ = 9
```

I need to "delay" (offset) this list by off = 3 (but this number, 3, might be variable) by adding "0" for the first "off" values and then starting from the "off+1" with the value in position "0" of the List:

```
OffsetList = [0,0,0,4,5,6,7,8,9]   #__len__ = 9
```

I have thought about these two possible solutions, but I'm pretty new to programming and I would like to get an opinion from someone both in terms of what is the most optimized solution, as well as if it's possible to develop a different solution which might better than the ones I've thought about:

```
#SOLUTION 1
OffsetList = []
for _ in range(0,off):
    OffsetList.append(0)
for k in range(0, len(List) - off):
    OffsetList.append(List[k])
```

---

```
#SOLUTION 2
OffsetList = []
for _ in range(0,off):
    OffsetList.append(0)
j = 0
while len(OffsetList) < len(List):
    OffsetList.append(List[j])
    j += 1
```

Which one of the two you think is more optimized (fast, safe, stable etc.), and why? Plus (I'm sure), is there any better solution than the two I've thought about?

Comment: how are you using this list?

Comment: @JoelCornett I am filling it with values that I need for later comparison. Let's say, if the first list "List" is containing the variable "Price", I need the Offset list by 3 to compare "the price with its own value 3 days ago".

Comment: So the idea would be to create a third vector of Booleans that will have `True` if `List[k] < OffsetList[k]` and viceversa, and this should reproduce the human behavior "let me see if the price today is smaller than the price three days ago".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best bet is not to explicitly iterate through the list at all when adding the zeros

```
def prefix1(l, offset):
    return l = [0] * offset + l

def prefix2(l, offset):
    for _ in xrange(offset):
        l.insert(0, 0)
    return l

>>> %timeit prefix1([1,2,3,4,5], 500)
10000 loops, best of 3: 4.87 µs per loop
>>> %timeit prefix2([1,2,3,4,5], 500)
10000 loops, best of 3: 190 µs per loop
```

*Sidenote*: I'm using the iPython `%timeit` magic which uses Python's inbuilt `timeit` [module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html). You could also just call the time it module directly `python -m timeit --setup 'n=50;l=[1,2,3,4,5]' 'l = [0] * n + l'` but using iPython makes things a bit easier.

In general explicit looping in Python is slower than list comprehensions, this though does not apply to everything and doesn't mean that you should try to write everything as a list comprehension. See [this article](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions/). I don't see any reason why you would use a while loop when it is clear what you want, add `n` elements to the beginning of a list. That being the case I prefer code that says precisely that `l = [0] * offset + l` the intention of that is pretty clear.

From `JoelCornett`'s comment

```
import itertools

def prefix3(l, offset):
    return list(itertools.chain([0] * offset, l))

def prefix4(l, offset):
    return itertools.chain([0] * offset, l)

def prefix5(l, offset):
    return itertools.chain(itertools.repeat(0, offset), l)

>>> %timeit prefix3([1,2,3,4,5], 500)
10000 loops, best of 3: 13 µs per loop
>>> %timeit prefix4([1,2,3,4,5], 500)
10000 loops, best of 3: 2.9 µs per loop
>>> %timeit prefix5([1,2,3,4,5], 500)
10000 loops, best of 3: 883 ns per loop
```

Notice that `prefix5` is measured in nano seconds the others are micro seconds.

The difference between `prefix3` and `prefix4 & prefix5`  is that `itertools.chain` returns an iterator (no random access and you can't call `len` on it). So making that into a list in `prefix3` involves an overhead. If you are only interested in iterating over the elements, not accessing a specific one by index, you should go with `prefix5`, otherwise `prefix2` or `prefix3`.

Comment: Use `itertools.chain` to accomplish this.

Comment: As I said before I'm new to the programming world, and this %timeit method is pure gold for me to test my scripts. If you could please give your opinion about the problem to answer my question, I will select this as favorite answer despite all the others were great as well.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ how do you mean my opinion about the problem?

Comment: @MattiLyra, Well, we have figured out neither the while nor the for I've thought about are good solutions. Some say list comprehension, some others list slicing... what would you think is best then?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I realised that the `[0] * offset` is costing you the most, so replacing that with `itertools.repeat` makes things go even faster, see `prefix5`

Answer (score 3):

You can use list slicing:

```
>>> List = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> off = 3
>>> OffsetList = [0]*len(List)
>>> OffsetList[off:] = List[:-off]
>>> OffsetList
[0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehensions for this sort of thing:

```
List = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
off = 3
OffsetList = [0 for x in xrange(off)] + List[:-off]
print OffsetList
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> off = 3
>>> [0] * off + l[:-off]
[0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> List = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] 
>>> off = 3
>>> OffsetList = [0] * off + List[:-off]
>>> print (OffsetList)

>>> [0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```